# No empty spaces? React + MUI Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, material-ui, jsx

I'm using Material UI Grid to make an image grid and I'm trying to get rid of the empty spaces between some grid items. I've tried changing the alignitems and justify values of the container, but it didn't work.
See image.[image: Grid]

```
    return <Grid container alignItems="flex-start" justify="center" className="img-container" spacing={2}>
        {/* All images */}
        {docs && docs
            .map(image => (
                // In a grid item
                <Grid className="img-item" item key={image.id} xs={12} md={6} lg={4}>
                    {/* all accounts */}
                    {docs2 && docs2
                        .filter((user) => image.userID === user.userID)
                        .map(user => (
                            <div key={image.id} className="div">
                                <img src={image.url} alt="uploaded pic" />
                                <Typography variant="subtitle1"> By {user.userName}

                                    {/* Delete button only renders if currentUser.uid === image.userID*/}
                                    {handleButton(image.userID) &&
                                        <IconButton
                                            color="secondary" aria-label="delete image"
                                            onClick={() => handleDeleteImage(image.id, 
                                            image.userID, image.name)}
                                            component="span" >
                                            <DeleteForever />
                                        </IconButton>}
                                </Typography>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                </Grid>
            ))}
    </Grid>
}
```

Comment: In the case of images, the spacing also depends on the dimensions of the image. If the image is not the height as required by the `GridItem` or if images are of different heights (the looks here), then there'll be some empty spaces..

Comment: So it’s not possible to adjust the height of the grid item based on the image that’s inside it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `Grid container`, `Grid item` takes the size of its content in that case its image, but the `Grid container` takes the size of the Larger `Grid item` in your case the first `Grid item` that's why the following Grids have spaces below.

In your case, dealing with list of images you should use `GridList` component not `Grid`.
Follow this link for more details about it https://material-ui.com/components/grid-list/